# Android radio button is changing id between fragments

Tags: android, radio-button, persistence

I have a set of dynamically created fragments for a survey application that I'm building. In each created fragment is a generated question and dynamically created radio buttons for multiple choice answers.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_survey_page, container, false);
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.aQuestion)).setText(question);

    // create radio buttons, Set the answers
    rGroup = ((RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup));
    for (int j = 0; j < answers.size(); j++) {
        HashMap answer = (HashMap) answers.get(j);
        RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(getActivity(),null,0,R.style.rButton);
        rdbtn.setText(answer.get("aName").toString());
        rGroup.addView(rdbtn);
    }

    // and add a listener
    rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId){
            RadioButton checkedRadioButton = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(checkedId);
            String text = checkedRadioButton.getText().toString();
            savedChecked = checkedId;
            try {
                Log.d("RADIO",""+rGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                questions.put("answer", text);
                listener.putAnswer(questions);
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
return rootView;
}
```

As the choice is checked, a new fragment with a new question and set of possible answers is created.

How do I get the state of the radio buttons to stay between fragments? I've tried storing their ID in system preferences but when you navigate back the ID changes. Say it starts at 1, you navigate away, mark another radio button, navigate back and the ID (1) is different.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: the checkedId is getting modified each time as you are storing them in savedChecked and updating the value in prefs.

Instead you can try adding the values in a list so that each response will be stored separately which will solve the overwrite issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the value to stick around by adding an Id to the radio button with a set value.

```
rGroup = ((RadioGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radiogroup));
    for (int j = 0; j < answers.size(); j++) {
        HashMap answer = (HashMap) answers.get(j);
        RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(getActivity(),null,0,R.style.rButton);
        rdbtn.setText(answer.get("aName").toString());
        rdbtn.setId(Integer.parseInt(answer.get("aId").toString()));
        rGroup.addView(rdbtn);
    }
```